# Rails 6 and Tailwind CSS does not deploy to Heroku

Tags: heroku, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, tailwind-css

I have a Rails 6 app that was successfully deployed to Heroku and worked on localhost:3000.

I added tailwindcss via yarn and webpack. It runs perfectly fine on localhost, but does not run on heroku. When I run `heroku logs` I get the following error

[image: console error logs]

I've read all the Heroku Rails 6 Webpacker issues, and tried all the suggestions. Nothing worked.

1. I have commented out `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag %>` ... didn't help
2. I have toggled `extract_css: true` in webpacker.yml file .... didn't help
3. I have run

   - `heroku buildpacks:clear`
   - `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`
   - `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby` 
     ... didn't help

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

My github repo is https://github.com/HundredBillion/enneagram

Comment: where you able to fix it?

Comment: no - ended up creating a bootstrap rails project and just pushed that to Heroku.

Answer (score 7):

Stumbled across this post while stuck on a similar problem, hopefully this info will help someone in the future.

I solved my issue within the package.json file by moving the "tailwindcss" reference from the devDependencies to the dependencies block.

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.2.0",  // <--- Now here.
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
                                    //<--- Was here.
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with you but I tried this one and it worked for me.

> Inside of config/webpacker.yml, you must set extract_css: true default is false.

Comment: This was the issue for me - this setting needed to be `true` for all environments, and I also needed `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>` to be included in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: Same here @BobWhitelock. Did you also remove the default `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` and add `media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` to the `stylesheet_pack_tag`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for you, let me know which one (if any) work for you.

In webpacker.yml for all instances of the below options

```
check_yarn_integrity: false
compile: true
```

Try

```
./bin/setup
rails webpacker:clobber
rails webpacker:compile
```

If none of the above work then perhaps one of these links will help:

- https://github.com/tailwindcss/discuss/issues/4#issuecomment-341918136
- https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails

Comment: thanks for this info. it didn't help but I'm going to keep trying other options.

Comment: Is this for prod?

Comment: @StevenAguilar - yes it's for production

Answer (score 0):

I had a different error where after updating/fiddling with tailwind my create-react-app  wouldn't deploy (highly likely something it did).

my buildpack was node.js. changed per https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-troubleshooting

Confirm that your app is using this buildpack:

heroku buildpacks
If it's not using create-react-app-buildpack, then set it:

heroku buildpacks:set mars/create-react-app
…and deploy with the new buildpack:

git commit --allow-empty -m 'Switch to create-react-app-buildpack'
git push heroku master